# cancel script execution and continue

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a script which runs another script.

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

....
cd /folder/
sh run.sh
sh another_script
...
```

the procedure:

So , I start running myscript.sh , the script runs it's commands.

Then, it gets to `run.sh` script ,which eventually ( the `run.sh` ) starts to serve on port 8080.At this time , I just want to stop it ( the `run.sh` ).And continue with the rest of the `myscript.sh`.

Comment: Would not it be simpler saying you want to serve the output of another_script at port 8080? Is it what you want?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro:As I said  , I am runnning a script which contains various commands.When it hits the `sh run.sh` , the `run.sh` script will start to server ( after a few seconds or minute ) at 8080.Then, I just want to cancel it ,stop it.And then , continue with the rest of the script.

Comment: Please read you question (out load), and where it does not make sense, amend it, so that it does.

Comment: @richard:I updated .I hope it is more clear..

Comment: @richard:Can you let me know at which point you have problem?

Comment: @richard:I meant problem to understand.Now,if you understand that I said it is your problem in general , then ,it's not my problem!

Comment: It sounds to me like the easiest thing to do would be to comment out the `sh run.sh` line since you don't want to run it ("I just want to cancel it, stop it"). If you terminate it anyway, why bother starting it? If something needs to start in the background, use `&` at the end of its invocation, and save its PID (`$!`) if you want to keep track of it for same reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what `sh run.sh` is for.  Two likely possibilities, *either*:

1. `run.sh` starts a server that needs to keep running, (and let's say this server needs a little time to get going), try:

   ```
   sh run.sh &  sleep 15s
   ```

*Or*:

2. `run.sh` does a few things with I/O, tweaks a file or two, starts a server to do some work, and needs a little time to do the work, but just doesn't know when to quit, try:

   ```
   timeout 15s sh run.sh
   ```

Comment: @arc:Can't I , after the run.sh finishes it's work  , hence start to server at 8080, cancel it?Like pressing ctrl+c ?And continue with the rest of the script?(of course the timeout in 2 option you have does it's work!Thanks